# How to make timer before multiplayer game start in unity 5.?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, unity-networking

Here I am trying to create a multiplayer game. I want to put timer before game start so, I do research, but can't get any solution for this. I am currently using
"Coroutine" for this. but not working.it show different time for all players.

```
private int j = 10;

void Start()
{
    if (isLocalPlayer)
    StartCoroutine (GameStartTimer ());
}


IEnumerator GameStartTimer()
{
    while (j > 0) {
        j = j - 1;
        Debug.Log ("Value of j is : " + j);
        startTimertext.text = j.ToString ();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);
    }
    //ObjectParentingSystem ();
    GetPlayerAnimandRGB ();
    StartCoroutine (StartPlayerTimer ());
    //yield return new WaitForSeconds (10);
    gameStartTextPanel.SetActive (false);
}
```

I also try below code but, can't get succes.

```
void Start()
{
    if (isServer){
        StartCoroutine (GameStartTimer ());   
    }
    else{
        GetPlayerAnimandRGB ();
        StartCoroutine (StartPlayerTimer ());
        //yield return new WaitForSeconds (10);
        gameStartTextPanel.SetActive (false);
    }
}
```

If any one have code for this or tutorials then pls share link.

Comment: Why exactly do you need the timer? What is its purpose? Of course the value is different for every player, because any player calls start at a different time (if i understand it correctly)

Comment: I am creating game with rounds like 1, 2 or 3. so, After every round timer should start to give a less time like 10 to 15 sec to my game player to set again.

Comment: Your second code that's not working, that should be `Start` not `start`.

Comment: How different are the numbers? Completely different or minor desync?

Comment: @someone I can't understand what you say, I simply explain, take a card game for example. After every round there a timer 10 to 15 second for player to be ready for next round. value of j is 10

Comment: Does it display 12345 seconds for one player and 1337 for the other or does it display 5 seconds for one and 6 for other?

Comment: @someone If I try first code. it play timer locally. so first player(Host) timer stoped, but second (client) timer is running still. and second code is not working.

Comment: @black you are right every player connect at different time. but I want to connect player if timer is not zero, then after no one can connect. so, I want to put timer for this reason. other player need to wait for next round. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this right, you've a wait timer that keeps ticking for 10 seconds. Once this is zero, the start game timer begins and only those connected can play the game.

To keep all players and timers in sync you will have to either designate one client as the server responsible for keeping all other clients in sync or have a server broadcast the time to all players who connect to the room. Without this, you will not be able to keep the time in sync as players don't join the room at the same time.